# How web app can used offlinely base on Service Worker?

Tags: web, service-worker

I know there are many documents about Service Worker, also many questions already asked.

But today is a long day with me, so I'm very tired to read many many docs now.

I just want to explain my thinking about **Service Worker, how it helps us serve web app offline**, and I hope everybody can tell me whether it's right or not.

Everything I know about **Service Worker** is it ***intercepts*** on the **network request job** of browser, and do something. So I guess when it intercepts, it will cached every request. So when the network isn't connected, **Service Worker** uses the data it cached for serving to the users

Thanks for all reply,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your thoughts are right. Here I will provide some more details about the whole functioning.

A **service worker** (SW), like a web worker, runs on different thread than the one used by the main web app. This allows SW to keep running even when the web app is not opened, allowing for instance to receive and show web notifications.

A SW, differently from a web worker, used for generic purposes, acts specifically as a **proxy** between  our web application and the network. However is up to us to define and implement what and how the SW has to cache data locally, otherwise, by default, the SW doesn't know what to store in the cache.

For this we have to implement **caching strategies** that target static assets (like .js or .css files, for instance) or even URLs (but keep in mind that the CACHE API, used by the SW, can only cache GET calls, no PUT/POST).
Once the assets or URLs we are interested are defined within the scope of a specific strategy, the SW will intercept all outgoing requests and see  if there is a match and eventually provide the data from the local cache, instead of going over the network.

Of course this depends on the strategy we chose/implement.

Since the requested data is already available locally, the SW can deliver it even when the user is offline.

If interested, [I wrote an article, describing in detail the service worker](https://dev.to/paco_ita/service-workers-and-caching-strategies-explained-step-3-m4f)s and some of the most common caching strategies, applied to different scenarios.